# Is there a way to receive security updates after vendor stops them, without compromising SafetyNet attestation?

Tags: updates, security, vanilla-android, safety-net

Imagine the following situation:

- The vendor of my phone has stopped providing security patches for the stock OS.
- The HW is perfectly fine and powerful enough for years to come, so I'm definitely not willing to replace it just to get access to security patches.
- Running a phone OS with unfixed security vulnerabilities makes me uneasy. (It feels insane enough to run a computer at home with an OS that's a year behind on security patches. It's twice as insane to do the same with a device that I routinely take to all kinds of hostile environments and untrusted networks.)
- Authors of all kinds of random apps have grown a habit of requiring SafetyNet attestation.
- I don't need root access to my phone, and I can live with losing some of the proprietary vendor-provided features. I also don't care too much about running the latest Android version, as long as it's receiving security fixes and is compatible with most apps.

I know I have the following two options:

- Stick to the stock vendor OS, which is gradually going to become full of security holes. However, SafetyNet passes and I can run all kinds of apps because they feel safe on my device.
- Install a custom OS. This will fail SafetyNet, unless I use a tool to hack around it and try to pretend the phone is not rooted. This approach is likely to stop working at some point, leaving me with a device that fails SafetyNet. Thus although my device may have up-to-date security patches, apps will refuse to run because they deem the device insecure.

**Is there a third way, which would let me stay up-to-date on security patches while not breaking SafetyNet?** I can imagine something like a pure AOSP system, perhaps built and signed by Google or another vendor, that I could run unrooted and unmodified (relying on vendor drivers through the Treble thing).

Comment: Is it important to you what Android version the device will run – or could you e.g. live with the device staying on Oreo (Android 8) provided it still gets the security fixes? I'm not certain how long this holds true, but AFAIK eg LineageOS with Magisk can still pass SafetyNet up to a point. I'm not sure about what that point was, as I never cared about "fake safety" (SafetyNet saying "all safe" even if your last security patch arrived 3 years ago). Might be worth investigating that path.

Comment: @Izzy I don't care too much, within reasonable bounds. I just need it to be compatible with most apps in the store (thus Oreo is likely fine, Jellybean isn't).

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant (and btw I doubt Magisk would be available for JB ;) As I wrote, I've not followed up things. I just remember having seen Magisk passing SafetyNet in the past – and you need an unlocked bootloader to get Magisk running, so counting 1+1 made me leaving that comment…

Comment: A passed SafetyNet attestation does not say anything if your device is secure or safe. It just checks if it is in the original state. At the moment it is really a shame that Android device only get update for a few months, especially comparing it to iOS :(

Comment: @Robert Yes, I also fail to see why app authors insist on SafetyNet given that there are much worse vulnerabilities not accounted for by SafetyNet validation, but that's still what they do, so my question is how best to live with it.

Comment: As Izzy wrote you can try Magisk and MagiskHide but that can break SafetyNet at any time. Google already tried a SafetyNet version that can no longer be bypassed using Magisk. At the moment it in unclear why Google now again uses the old test that can be bypassed.

Comment: Give a try to custom ROMs with Magisk. SafetyNet is still passing by magisk. If hardware backed attestation is enforced for your device, switch to stock ROM again.